# pandas dataframe find last value lower than certain value in the column within group

Tags: pandas

Have a pandas dataframe,need to find last value lower than certain value in the column within group.

```
     dataframe is as following:
     region    year   month      signal
     A         2010   2          20
     A         2010   3          32
     A         2010   4          24
     A         2010   6          50
     .......
     A         2011   1          20
     .......
     B         2010   2          100
     B         2010   3           20
     .......
```

Now I need add one column of flag to label the last value lower than 25 in the first half year for  each ["region","year"] combination. So for example for  region A in the first half year of 2010, April  signal value will be labeled as 1.
Any suggestion for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter rows by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and conditions for less by [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html), then use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://andas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for last values of combinations `region` and `year`. Assign to column with [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for replace misisng values to `False` and last map `True->1` and `False->0` by convert mask to integers

```
m = ~df.loc[df['month'].lt(7) & df['signal'].lt(25)].duplicated(['region','year'], keep='last')

df['new'] = m.reindex(df.index, fill_value=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  region  year  month  signal  new
0      A  2010      2      20    0
1      A  2010      3      32    0
2      A  2010      4      24    1
3      A  2010      6      50    0
4      A  2011      1      20    1
5      B  2010      2     100    0
6      B  2010      3      20    1
```

Comment: This is beautifully written.